# Proper resizing of Log File after shrinking - SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012, transaction-log

Recently I've discovered our 2012 SQL Server database contains over 100,000 Virtual Log files by running the DBCC LOGINFO command. After doing a good deal of research 
I am still uneasy as to what exact size I should set the Log after shrinking.

With using the code snippet below and based on my details, what suggested size should I set my Log file to and would you recommend that I change my autogrowth?

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
BACKUP LOG AdventureWorks TO DISK='d:\adtlog.bak'
GO
-- Get Logical file name of the log file
sp_helpfile
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE(AdventureWorks_Log,TRUNCATEONLY)
GO
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks
MODIFY FILE
(NAME = AdventureWorks_Log,SIZE = 1GB)
GO
DBCC LOGINFO
GO
```

- Current Database Size: 39,482,368 KB
- Initial Database Size: 38,557,000 KB
- AutoGrowth: 128 MB
- Current Log File Size: 34,964,480 KB
- Initial Log File Size: 34,145,000 KB
- AutoGrowth: 128 MB

A Log backup is taken 8 times a day 6 days a week and Autogrowth is happening pretty much once a week. The Log file is also on a separate storage device from the Database

Also: Many of the VLF's are probably left over from the last DBA not shrinking the file. It has been within a year or two since we updated the autogrowth to 128 MB from the default and set this initial size.

Comment: I do not understand. The backup log should clear the log. Are you shrinking the log file after each backup and then asking why are you have growth?

Comment: Let my clarify. Our TRN Files for the log backups every 2 hours are on average around 20,000 KB but the overall Sql Server Database Transaction log file is 34,964,480 KB which is what continues to grow in size with the autogrowth. The backup is through a maintenance plan, I don't think it is shrinking after each backup.

Comment: So for this exact question I'm wondering if for a one-time shrink and regrow, whats a reasonable size to set my initial size to after I shrink the log so that I don't have autogrowth occuring immediately and frequently

Comment: Correction: the individual backups to appear to shrink automatically its the 34GB database log file that does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find a good starting point here - [Set transaction log size and growth](http://blog.sqlxdetails.com/set-transaction-log-initial-size/)

To summarize from the link:

- Set your transaction log large enough so it will not grow during
  normal operation. All update activity stops in the database when the
  logs grows, so you want to minimize log growths.
- **For an initial log size, you could roughly estimate the log size
  needed to rebuild your largest table in db (roughly, that is the size
  of that table) and set the initial log size to that value. That would
  be the “fit largest transaction” method. Imprecise, but is very
  simple.**
- Log file growth should be changed from a percentage (as is the
  default) to a fixed MB size and monitored.
- The link references the usage of BULK RECOVERY model to limit the
  size of the transaction log due to 'minimally logged' transactions
  like BULK INSERT and INDEX REBUILDS. You can only switch to BULK
  RECOVERY from FULL RECOVERY, but you should be aware that you cannot
  restore to a point of time that encompasses a 'minimally logged'
  transaction because individual log (insert/update/delete) records are
  not generated during that process. While the actual log file will not
  be large for a 'minimally logged' transaction, the log backup will
  still be large due to backing up the changed data extents that were
  affected during the 'minimally logged' transaction.
- In FULL RECOVERY, the transaction log will continue to grow until a
  log backup occurs (assuming there aren't any open transactions left)
- In SIMPLE RECOVERY, the transaction log is 'basically' available for
  reuse after a transaction commits work.
- Generally speaking, shrinking the log is discouraged. At some point,
  there was activity that caused it to grow to that size (index
  rebuild, etc.). There may be situations where an out-of-the-normal
  issue occurred and caused the transaction to grow large than normally
  needed and in those cases you may need to shrink the log down to a
  more realistic size

---

On a side note, your question states you are taking transaction log backups 8 times per day (6 days per week).  I would highly encourage you to read [Back Up Transaction Logs Every Minute. Yes, Really.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/02/back-transaction-logs-every-minute-yes-really/)

Comment: I still have a little confusion in the area of, Since my current Log file is about 35GB should I base the initial size off of that seeing as how it was set at 34GB awhile ago by a DBA (he never shrunk the file) or after I shrink the log I should be looking at a combination of the size of our log TRN files for a week or month and base it off of that? Closer to 35GB or more like 1GB initial size?

Comment: The biggest reason for wanting to shrink the file is to remove those 100,000 vlf's which we believe may be hurting performance

Comment: @user3841709 - can you restore this database to a test server and shrink the log down to something like 10gb - then try rebuilding the largest table/index and note the transaction log growth - that might be the number you shrink your production log down to.

Comment: I can do that, I'll see what results I get if everything goes smoothly

Comment: @user3841709 - you might also consider increasing the log growth value from 128mb to 1gb.  The growth event will take longer, but you'll have fewer of them.

Comment: Is there a recommended time frame for how often autogrowth should occur? Ours currently has been every week but at the same time you don't want to set the initial size so large that you will never hit autogrowth do you?

Comment: After rebuilding the index on the largest indexed table my overall transaction Log File bumped up from 10GB to 18GB. Would my 34 GB initial size that it currently is set to still be reasonable or should I reduce initial size in this case ?

Comment: @user3841709 - for me personally, I'd probably shrink your production log down to 20gb and modify the growth to 1,000mb (1gb) and monitor.  the goal is to NOT have any autogrowths after stabilizing the size